# Parser HTML DOM OU REGEX PHP

Tags: php, parser

Tenho o seguinte **html** que a função **curl** me retorna

```
<div class="balance-amounts box-container mp-box-shadow  bg-trama">
            <div class="ch-g1-2">
              <dl class="balance-amounts__list available-money">
                <dt>Disponível</dt>
                <dd class="price price-large mlb">
                <span class="price-symbol">R$</span> <span class="price-integer">0</span><span class="price-decimal-mark">,</span><span class="price-decimal">00</span>
                </dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="balance-amounts__list account-money">
                <dt>Em conta</dt>
                <dd class="price">
                <span class="price-symbol">R$</span> <span class="price-integer">24</span><span class="price-decimal-mark">,</span><span class="price-decimal">99</span>
                </dd>
              </dl>
            </div>

            <div class="ch-g1-2">
              <dl class="balance-amounts__list other-types-money">
                <dt>Não disponível</dt>
                <dd class="price">
                <span class="price-symbol">R$</span> <span class="price-integer">24</span><span class="price-decimal-mark">,</span><span class="price-decimal">99</span>
                </dd>
              </dl>
              <dl class="balance-amounts__list other-types-money">
                <dt>Em mediação</dt>
                <dd class="price">
                <span class="price-symbol">R$</span> <span class="price-integer">0</span><span class="price-decimal-mark">,</span><span class="price-decimal">00</span>
              </dd></dl>
              <dl class="balance-amounts__list other-types-money">
                <dt>Operações contestadas</dt>
                <dd class="price">
                <span class="price-symbol">R$</span> <span class="price-integer">0</span><span class="price-decimal-mark">,</span><span class="price-decimal">00</span>
                </dd>
              </dl>

            </div>
```

e preciso pega os valores dessa forma

```
 Disponível R$ 0,00 Em conta R$ 24,99 Não disponível R$ 24,99  Em mediação R$ 0,00 Operações contestadas R$ 0,00
```

alguma ideia de como posso fazer ?

Comment: Wender dá uma olhada a essa resposta `^` e vê a técnica resolve o teu problema.